# Sample size - prioritizing issues

Tags: sample-size

Hi I am about to distribute a survey that asks stakeholders to pick from a list of 20 issues, the top 3 they feel are important. I am not doing any hypothesis testing but ranking the results based on points. Is there any way I calculate an approximate sample size if my audience is 13000 people and I'd like a power of 0.8 and confidence of 95%. My objective is to list the top 3 chosen overall, ranked on points.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your research question is about prevalence rather than hypothesis testing, and hence the sample size should be based on accuracy rather than power. One fairly simplistic suggestion is that a sample size of 377 out of 13000 would provide the prevalence of those ranking any particular choice as number 1 with +/- 5% accuracy with 95% confidence. I'd be interested to hear other suggestions.